# YQL returning duplicate results for title and dc:title

Tags: xml, rss, yql

I am using YQL to parse multiple rss feeds.  I have success getting YQL to return the XML for title,link,date but it also pulls in dc:title which makes for duplicate results.  I have tried using dc:title but get a syntax error.  Here's the YQL statement.

```
    select title,link,description,date from rss where url in (
    'http://somerssfeed.com',
    'http://somerssfeed.com'
) | sort(field="date", descending="true")
```

What would be the correct syntax to use dc:title?
Also, is it possible for YQL to rename dc:title in the xml output to just title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen, YQL ignores namespaces when you specify the [projection](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/projection.html) (the fields to retrieve).  So, the correct *syntax* is what you already have; you cannot differentiate the `title` and `dc:title` fields in the manner that you want.

You could however manipulate the data in any way that you like (including removing, renaming, reordering of fields/results) in a bespoke [data table](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-reference.html).

If that sounds like too much hard work, you *could* append a [`unique()` filter](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/sorting.html) to the end of your existing query to return only one result per unique `title`/`dc:title`, to merge the duplicates that you are getting, like `… | unique(field="title")`.

Comment: Thanks.  Was hoping there was a simpler solution.  I have already implemented the unique filter as mentioned, and it works fine.